# How to get raw hadoop metrics

Tags: hadoop, monitoring

sorry if this question is a duplicate, so far I haven't been able to find a satisfactory answer.

Is it possible to get the raw data of hadoop2 metrics? (e.g. in text file/json format)

According to https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/GangliaMetrics, I know that I can use ganglia (or maybe nagios) to get the metrics and monitor hadoop cluster. However, what I want is the raw data, for my own analysis purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen the following links
[link1](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/10/what-is-hadoop-metrics2/) and [link2](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/03/hadoop-metrics/). They clearly mentioned which metrics we can dump, and how to use sinks to store them